# using FormData() in react keeps returning null

Tags: reactjs, axios, form-data

I am building a React app and in it there's a part where i should set up a profile picture, but every time i call the `api` i keep getting an error that i haven't filled one of the fields for the post api to return a success response.

this is my jsx

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="file" onChange={(e) => this.handleFile(e)}></input>
    <button type="button" onClick={(e) => this.handleUpload(e)} >send</button>
</form>
```

and here is the code i'm using to handle those

```
state = {
   file: null
};
handleFile(e) {
   console.log(e.target.files, "ssss");
    console.log(e.target.files[0], "ssss");
    let file = e.target.files

    this.setState({ file: e })
}
handleUpload(e) {
  let file = this.state.file
  let fromdata = new FormData();
  fromdata.append('image', file);
  fromdata.append('name', "filedata");
  const headers = {
        Authorization': localStorage.getItem('api_key'),

  }
  const user = {
       filedata: fromdata,
       type: 1,
  };
  axios.post(`sth sth`, user, {
       headers: headers
  })
       .then(res => {
           console.log(res);
           console.log(res.data);
        })
}
```

so basically the server requires `type` and `filedata` but every time i send an `api` request it keeps returning me

```
filedata: ["The filedata field is required."]
```

and i can't seem to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to upload a single file, The problem I see is in setting the file to state. You are putting the entire response into the state in this statement: `this.setState({ file: e })` change it to  `this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })`.

Basically you are taking in more than just the file, you are taking in the entire response and other data that comes in when a user uploads a file using the choose file input button and because of that things can't be read well.

My practice: I would put the file into a global `var` instead of the state.

Usually in cases like this, its the function that doesn't complete but the main thread keeps on running, thats why variables state null or older value.

```
var file, fromdata;

handleFile(e) {
    file = e.target.files[0];
}
handleUpload(e) {
    fromdata = new FormData(); //make sure this statement completes before moving any further
    fromdata.append('image', file);
    fromdata.append('name', "filedata");
    const headers = {
        Authorization': localStorage.getItem('api_key'),

    }
    user = {
        filedata: fromdata,
        type: 1,
    };
    axios.post(`sth sth`, user, {
        headers: headers
    })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
}
```

Comment: nah, it keeps returning that even after i changed it.

Comment: @thepreacher are you updating the `const user` If this is the code that does all then, `const user` has no data in it, therefore the error message.

Comment: so whenever i choose a photo the setState updates file and after that when i click send the variable file uses that state to get the value so i guess it get's updated, doesn't it?

Comment: @thepreacher no I don't think the const user is being touched, even tho you are creating a new FormData()

Comment: well even when i put {filedata:fromdata} instead of user i keep getting that error

Comment: @thepreacher you need to remove `const` from the user, can't change a constant value, and also know that let can't be accessed outside a function, I will write a code, that will explain it

Answer (score 1):

Work on your handleFile function properly and add a Content-Type/Accept header to your api request, your final code should look something like this. on your api console.log (req.file) you should see your file now reaches server successfully, or if you can provide a bit of your server code, I can be able to help further.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            file : null
        }
        this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this)
        this.handleUpload = this.handleUpload.bind(this)
    }

    handleFile(e) {
        let file = e.target.files[0]
        this.setState({ file })
    }

    handleUpload (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let file = this.state.file
        let fromdata = new FormData();
        fromdata.append('image', file);
        const headers = {
                'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('api_key'),
                'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
        }
        const user = {
            filedata: fromdata,
            type: 1,
        };
        axios.post(`sth sth`, user, {
            headers
        })
       .then(res => {
           console.log(res);
           console.log(res.data);
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleUpload}>
                <label>File</label><br/>
                    <input type='file' onChange={this.handleFile}/>
                <button>Send File!</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but i still get that error, when i put a string in front of filedata in user like filedata: "sth sth" it Successfully sends it, but it seems like it has problem getting it from DataForm, and is it possible that it may be a server side problem?

Comment: actually when i send a string or something like that i get a message saying "Call to a member function move() on null"

Comment: Send me the server side code, are you writing it in Nodejs or Python? If any of those you can share will help you look through