# filepond Field Name is required laravel api

Tags: reactjs, laravel, filepond

Hello I have a problem when uploading files to my current URL

this is my code

```
<FilePond
                            name='passport'
                            server={{
                                process: {
                                    url: 'http://sub.gulflandproperty.net/api/admin/v1/storepassport',
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    withCredentials: false,
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'AUTHORIZATION': 'Bearer ' + admin_token
                                    },
                                    ondata: (formData) => {
                                        formData.append('passport', Passport)
                                        console.log(formData)
                                        return formData
                                    },
                                    name: 'passport'
                                },
                            }}

                            allowMultiple={false}
                            instantUpload={false}
                            allowFileTypeValidation={true}
                            maxFiles={1}
                            labelIdle='Upload Passport Here (<span class="filepond--label-action"> PDF only </span>)'
                        />
```

and am getting this error from the API response

{"status":201,"errors":{"passport":["The passport field is required."]}}

how can i solve this

Comment: What value you are getting in console? because the value of formData is always {foo: undefined, bar: undefined}.

Comment: @Tayyabmehar the formData is empty

Comment: Log the `FormData` object like this instead of using `console.log` // Display the key/value pairs
for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]);
}

Answer (score 0):

The value of formData is always {foo: undefined, bar: undefined}.
Kindly review the below reply on stalkoverflow.
YOu will find your answer.

[using FormData() in react keeps returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756188/using-formdata-in-react-keeps-returning-null)